# Gradle Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath':

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Per the documentation on GitHub my build.gradle(app) is:

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.dubsmash.volley:library:2.0.1'
    compile 'ca.mimic:oauth2library:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.github.kittinunf.fuel:fuel:<latest-version>' //for JVM
    compile 'com.github.kittinunf.fuel:fuel-android:<latest-version>' //for Android
    compile 'com.github.kittinunf.fuel:fuel-livedata:<latest-version>' //for LiveData support
    compile 'com.github.kittinunf.fuel:fuel-rxjava:<latest-version>' //for RxJava support
    compile 'com.github.kittinunf.fuel:fuel-gson:<latest-version>' //for Gson support
    compile 'com.github.kittinunf.fuel:fuel-jackson:<latest-version>' //for Jackson support
}
```

And when I try to build Gradle throws the following error for all the fuel components:

```
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.github.kittinunf.fuel:fuel-livedata:<latest-version>.

Could not resolve com.github.kittinunf.fuel:fuel-livedata:<latest-version>.
Required by:
    project :app
 > No cached version of com.github.kittinunf.fuel:fuel-livedata:<latest-version> available for offline mode.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't actually write `"<latest-version>"` in a gradle compile block.

You have to substitute it for the version number.

So it'd be something like:

```
compile 'com.github.kittinunf.fuel:fuel:2.2.0'
```

Again, substitute the version number for the version you want.

Comment: That said, you *can* use the `+` notation. See: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html#sec:declaring_your_dependencies

Comment: So I am on GitHub looking at the package and it's dependencies, how do I tell the version of the various packages.(Sorry for the newbie question)

Comment: I saw the + in another SO question, tried it and it did not work.

Comment: I try to avoid even mentioning the possibility of '´+', as it's horrible to use, and will lead to issues when it's always upgrading to newest version, which doesn't handle API changes.

Comment: On their Github page there is a tab called "Releases", click it, and see the version number for the newest one.

Comment: @Moonbloom, got it, thank you. It looks like I'm over that hurdle, thank you.